# Zend_Navigation multiple menus

Tags: zend-framework, navigation

How to have multiple menus on site?

Right now I have one top menu (items accessible via ACL privileges), but how to create second sidemenu?
On multiple pages I'm going to have multiple sidemenu.

The first way that I think it should work is to create one page tree file with two new properties - "position" (in format: "top" or "top|sidemenu") and "where2display" (in format: "controller:action|controller:action").
And in top.phtml or sidemenu.phtml check if position is top/sidemenu and the menu item could be visible for specify controller & action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as I said :) The feature is quite easy and elastic.

navigation.php

```
$siteMenu = array(
    array(
        'resource'   => 'superadmin:index',
        'privilege'  => 'index',
        'label'      => 'Dashboard',
        'module'     => 'superadmin',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'route'      => 'superadmin',
        'icon'       => 'icon-home',
    ),
    // ====================================== USERS
    array(
        'resource'   => 'superadmin:users',
        'privilege'  => 'index',
        'label'      => 'Users',
        'module'     => 'superadmin',
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action'     => 'index',
        'route'      => 'superadmin',
        'position'   => 'top|sidebar',
        'accessable' => 'users:*|multid:*',
        'pages'      => array(
            array(
                'resource'   => 'superadmin:users',
                'privilege'  => 'index',
                'label'      => 'Users list',
                'module'     => 'superadmin',
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'route'      => 'superadmin',
                'icon'       => 'icon-list',
                'position'  => 'top|sidebar',
                'accessable' => 'users:*|multid:*',
            ),
```

View Helper that will help exploding the custom navigation properties:

```
<?php

/**
 * Helper for building menu with Zend_Navigation
 *
 * @author      Szymon Bluma <szbluma@gmail.com>
 */
class MrBlue_Helper_Navigation
{

    /**
     * Is the $page visible on sidebar?
     *
     * @param Zend_Navigation_Page $page
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isSidebar(Zend_Navigation_Page $page)
    {
        if( isset($page->position) && in_array('sidebar',explode('|',$page->position)) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Is the #page visible on topmenu?
     *
     * @param Zend_Navigation_Page $page
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isTopmenu(Zend_Navigation_Page $page)
    {
        if( !isset($page->position) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if( in_array('top',explode('|',$page->position)) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Is the $page (mainly in sidebar) accessable in $position type menu?
     *
     * @param Zend_Navigation_Page  $page
     * @param string                $position   OPTIONAL menu type - top or sidebar
     * @return boolean
     */
    public static function isAccessable(Zend_Navigation_Page $page, $position='top')
    {
        if( $position=='top' || !isset($page->accessable) ) {
            return true;
        }

        $controller = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
        $action = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getActionName();
        $elements = explode('|',$page->accessable);

        if( in_array($controller.':*',$elements) || in_array($controller.':'.$action,$elements) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And the menu_left.phtml view file:

```
<?php if($this->container): ?>
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
            <?php if($this->navigation()->accept($page) && MrBlue_Helper_Navigation::isAccessable($page, 'sidebar')): ?>
                <?php if($page->isVisible() && MrBlue_Helper_Navigation::isSidebar($page)): ?>
                    <?php if(count($page->pages) > 0): ?>
                        <li class="nav-header"><?php if(isset($page->icon)): ?><span class="<?= $page->icon; ?> icon"></span> <?php endif; ?><?= $page->label; ?></li>
                            <?php foreach ($page->pages as $subPage): ?>
                                <?php if($subPage->isVisible() && MrBlue_Helper_Navigation::isSidebar($subPage)): ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->navigation()->accept($subPage) && MrBlue_Helper_Navigation::isAccessable($subPage, 'sidebar')): ?>
                                        <li<?php if($subPage->isActive()): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $subPage->href; ?>" title="<?= $subPage->label; ?>"><?php if(isset($subPage->icon)): ?><span class="<?= $subPage->icon; ?> icon"></span> <?php endif; ?><?= $subPage->label; ?></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li<?php if($page->isActive()): ?> class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <a href="<?php echo $page->href; ?>" title="<?= $page->label; ?>"><?php if(isset($page->icon)): ?><span class="<?= $page->icon; ?> icon"></span> <?php endif; ?><?= $page->label; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have also menu_top.phtml file - it's similar to the menu_left.phtml with their own methods from MrBlue_Helper_Navigation. Think and do it yourself ;)